# Busca do menor em log(n)

Tags: c

Olá. Estou precisando de uma estrutura de dados eficiente para se buscar o menor valor de um vetor desordenado, sendo que:

- O vetor não pode ser ordenado.
- O vetor deve ter a possibilidade de atualização do valores em log(n).
- A busca do menor valor do vetor deve ser em log(n).

Existe alguma estrutura de dados que atenda os requisitos?

Desde já agradeço a resposta e os exemplos :)

Comment: Um *min heap* atende esses requisitos, ainda que não seja propriamente "desordenado"

Comment: Já que o vetor não pode ser posteriormente ordenado, tenho uma pergunta: você pode inserir o item de modo que ele já fique ordenado?

Answer (score 3):

Cara, não é possível sem utilizar alguma outra estrutura. Pois como está desordenado, você só terá a certeza de que encontrou o menor se checar todos os valores.
Mas se você armazenar em uma estrutura como uma árvore, os valores já serão armazenados de forma ordenada.
Para a busca em uma vetor desordenado o pior caso sempre será O(n).